# Two reflections generating the Dihedral group $D_n$

Tags: group-theory, rotations, dihedral-groups, reflection, finitely-generated

Let $l_1$ and $l_2$ be two lines intersecting at an angle of $\pi/n$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $r_1$ and $r_2$ denote the reflection by $l_1$ and $l_2$ respectively. I am to show that $r_1$ and $r_2$ generate a Dihedral group $D_n$.

First I claim that $D_n$ can be generated by a reflection $r$ about a line and rotation by angle $2\pi/n$, $\rho_{2\pi/n}$, because reflection by any other line intersecting at an angle of $2\pi m/n$ can be obtained by first applying $\rho_{2\pi/n}$ $m$ times, followed by $r$, and then followed by $\rho_{2\pi/n}^{-1}$ $m$ times.

Then I deduce from drawing and basic geometry that
$$r_1 r_2 = \rho_{2\pi/n}$$

Therefore $r_1$ and $r_2$ generates a Dihedral group $D_n$.

I am not sure if my answer is correct or rigorous enough.

Comment: Replicated: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/589439/303887

Comment: Show that setting $r_1r_2=r$ and $r_1=s$, $\langle r,s\rangle$ presents the usual Dihedral group.

Answer (score 0):

I would add more information about what exactly the group you're generating is and its structure. In particular, the transformations should have the structure of D_n. In this case, the group elements are the transformations, and group operation is composition.

Keep in mind the group is more than just its elements -- you are showing the elements have a particular structure.